# Python and PyQt: on exit confirmation box callEvent() it's invoched two times

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm a newbie to Python and PyQt. I've tried to manage closeEvent to ask before to close mainwindow, but this work well only from 'X' button. From the QMEssageBox created to ask the user, callEvent() it's called two times.

This is the relevant part of the code :

```
    self.ui.actionChiudi.triggered.connect(self.close)

def closeEvent(self, event):
    #check presence of data in the table
    if self.csvViewer.rowCount() > 0:
        print event # only to analyze the caller
        #show a warning
        Error = QtGui.QMessageBox()
        Error.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Question)
        Error.setWindowTitle('ATTENZIONE !!')
        Error.setInformativeText(u"Sei sicuro di voler uscire?")
        Error.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        ret = Error.exec_()
        if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    else:
        #close directly
        event.accept()
```

'actionChiudi' is the menù item in the main menù.
For what I can understand, when use 'X' button, the function close() it's called only one time directly from mainwindow object, then close my app.
When use the menù item, the function create the new object 'QMessageBox' then call 'closeEvent()' one time for this object, then recall the same function for the mainwindow object. If this is correct, I don't know how to manage this.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the reported problem. A minimal example based on your code could look like [this](https://pastebin.com/jZPsR5e6), but that doesn't show the behaviour you describe. Are you sure you don't have additional signals connected to `self.close` somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

thankyou for your tips about howto construct a good example of code. Sorry but I'm new there, then I did not succeed in making a good example. But, in the meantime, I was thinking about the problem and, at the end, I've solved this with a little trick.

I've added a global variable that count if you are closing the main window, then at the other calls to closeEvent() avoid to recall the test procedure.
I've tried to create a class for the generation of QMessageBox external to main class, then to override closeEvent() of this object, but don't work. The only way that I've found is with global variable. The program continue to call two times closeEvent (one for the QMessageBox and one for the mainwindow) but now, the second time ignore to recall the test. It's a trick, it's not elegant, but it works for me.

The piece of code now is this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import datetime
import inspect
import csv
import codecs
import pymssql
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
import mainwindow
#import _winreg only on Microsoft platforms
import platform
winos = True
if os.name == 'nt' and platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import _winreg
    #other stuff needed under Windows
    import _mssql
    import decimal
    import uuid
    winos = True
else:
    winos = False

#other global variables
liccode = False
closemain = False


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = mainwindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # some stuff and widgets to visualize in the main window

        #connettors to menù functions; leave only the closing one
        self.ui.actionChiudi.triggered.connect(self.close)

    #override of closeEvent - there I think, it's better to work to separate
    #closeEvent for mainwindow from general closeEvent. But how?
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        global closemain
        #make evaluation test to decide how to work. Close directly or no?
        if self.csvViewer.rowCount() > 0 and not closemain:
            print event
            #show a warning
            Error = QtGui.QMessageBox()
            Error.setIcon(QtGui.QMessageBox.Question)
            Error.setWindowTitle('WARNING !!')
            Error.setInformativeText(u"Are you sure to leave?")
            Error.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel)
            ret = Error.exec_()
            if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok:
                closemain = True
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()
        else:
            #close directly
            event.accept()
  #start application and create main
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  my_mainWindow = MainWindow()
  my_mainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In any case, any advice is well accepted to make a better code. Thank you all!